# How to create a fixture ActsAsTaggableOn with FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, acts-as-taggable-on

How can i create a fixture for [ActsAsTaggableOn::tag](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) Using FactoryGirl ?

I tried :

/spec/factories/tags.rb

```
Factory.define ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag do |f|
  f.sequence(:name) { |n| "titre#{n}" }
end
```

/spec/controllers/books_controller.rb

```
it "should return 2 categories whith books" do

      fake_tag = Factory(:tag)
...

end
```

I get :

```
Failure/Error: fake_tag = Factory(:tag)
     ArgumentError:
       Factory not registered: tag
```

Thanks for your help,
Vincent

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess you're using a quite old version of factory girl. I encourage you to switch to the latest version if you're able to.

Answering your question, I think you need something like:

```
Factory.define :tag, :class => ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag do |f|
  f.sequence(:name) { |n| "titre#{n}" }
end
```

Check the Factory 1.3 doc [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/tree/v1.3.3). But as I told you before. Try to switch to a newer version.

Answer (score 7):

This is how I add tags (using `acts-as-taggable-on`) to my user model (using [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl)):

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :post do 
    ...
    trait :poetry do
      after(:create) { |post| post.update_attributes(tag_list: 'poetry') }
    end
  end
end
```

This way when I want to create just a regular `Post` object, I write:

```
post = create(:post)
```

but when I want to create a `Post` tagged with `poetry`, I write:

```
post = create(:post, :poetry)
```

And it works pretty well.